# Non-sticky service with interval task

Tags: android, intentservice

Assume the following code:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        getApplicationContext().startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class););
    }
}

public class MyService extends IntentService {

    private Handler mLoadContactsHandler;

    public MyService() {
        super(MyService.class.getName());
        myHandler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {    
        int delay = intent.getIntExtra("delay", 1000 * 60 * 5);
        myHandler.postDelayed(updateTask, delay);
    }

    private Runnable updateTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            Thread thread = new Thread()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    ... some task ...
                }
            };
            thread.start();

            myHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000*60*15);
        }
    };
}
```

Would this service keep running even if I exit the app? (Exit as in closing the app using back-button)

I mean, the service is never really finished. How can I make the service quit if the app has been shut down. Of course, I would like it to finish what it's doing.

Edit. I want the service to keep running on its interval as long as the app is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Would this service keep running even if I exit the app? (Exit as in closing the app using back-button)<p>
```

Yes, it would keep running unless android kills it, which it does few times a day.

```
How can I make the service quit if the app has been shut down. Of course, I would like it to finish what it's doing.<p>
```

AFAIK, one can know when an activity/service is destroyed but cannot know when an app is destroyed(reason being android likes to keep applications alive in memory, so there is no fixed time). So , I would suggest  you to call  `stopSelf();` as the last line in the run() method of your thread. That will stop your service after your thread has finished the task at hand.

```
public void run()
                {
                  //  ... some task ...

                stopSelf();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) instead so that the Android system will manage it (Like stopping the service when completed etc).

Comment: I am using IntentService. I want the service to keep running on its interval as long as the app is running, therefore it's never really completed.